# How to get displayID of display application currently displayed on?

Tags: macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I am trying something like

```
   CGPoint point = CGContextConvertPointToDeviceSpace(state->cgDrawContext, state->rect.origin);
    CGGetDisplaysWithPoint (point, 1, &display, &matchingDisplayCount);
```

while **state->rect** is CGRect  that is lately passed to **CGContextDrawImage**, which in her turn draw in application window.
But I always get main display (the one with 0,0 coordinates) id.
**CGContextConvertPointToDeviceSpace** documentation states that it transforms point to device space, so is it different from global coordinates space mentioned in other parts of documentation ?
And how can i get displayID of current display application is drawed on?

Comment: what is your `state->rect.origin`?  The window's origin?  Isn't that already in global coordinates?

Comment: rect.origin [3.000000 62.000000], rect[w,h]) [231.000000 36.000000]  
d0.origin [0.000000 0.000000], d0[width,height]) [1280.000000 800.000000] d1.origin [1280.000000 -713.000000], d1[w,h]) [1920.000000 1080.000000]

---

when rect stand for state-rect, and d0, d1 it is bounds of my displays. This print made while application located on second( right) monitor.

I am confident  that state->rect is in user space coordinates since it used in  CGContextDrawImage

Comment: is your `rect` on the main screen or on the secondary screen?  If it's on the main screen, move it to the second screen and then show me what the new rect.origin is.

Comment: sorry i sent the message too early, I updated it,  This print from second screen

Comment: @MichaelDautermann. I rechecked.  

  rect.origin [32.000000 42.000000], rect[w,h]) [843.000000 526.875000]  
  state->rect.origin [0.000000 0.000000], state->rect[w,h]) [1680.000000 1050.000000]  
rect iis after transformation, state->rect is one goes to CGContextDrawImage . Print  made when application located in the middle of the second monitor

Comment: Do you have a NSWindow or NSView that goes with that CGContext?

Comment: I didn't knew I can get NsView/NsWindow from CGContext. I'll try to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I also need to figure which display the application is drawn on in a multi-display scenario.